# Encoding strings using periodic table abbreviations

Tags: javascript, performance, strings

I took a JavaScript challenge to finish a task related to logo of "Breaking  Bad" where letters in your first name and last name are spotted with elements of periodic table and its respective atomic number. I wrote the below code, any suggestions to improve performance or any best coding practices

```
  function Process() {
    var ellist = {
        "h": "1",
        "he": "2",
        "li": "3",
        "be": "4",
        "b": "5",
        "c": "6",
         .
         .
         .
        "Lv":"116",
    "Uus":"117",
    "Uuo":"118"
    };
    var fname = document.getElementById("firstname");
    var lname = document.getElementById("lastname");
    var splits = fname.split("");
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
        var onevalue = fname.indexOf(splits[i]);
        var singlev = fname.substring(onevalue, onevalue + 1);
        var doublev = fname.substring(onevalue, onevalue + 2);
        var triplev = fname.substring(onevalue, onevalue + 3);
        if (ellist[splits[i]] || ellist[doublev] || ellist[triplev]) {
            value = splits[i];

            if (ellist[doublev] || ellist[triplev]) {
                value = ellist[doublev];

                if (ellist[triplev]) {
                    value = ellist[triplev];
                         // some code here
                }
       // some code here
            }
    // some code here
        }
    }
```

Using the Process() function which contains the logic. The object *ellist* contains the list of elements of periodic table with its atomic number. First name is taken from textbox on webpage and stored in *fname* and similarly the last name in *lname* and in the for loop it contains the code which checks whether the firstname contains the string which matches the elemetns of periodic table. Any suggestions?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++)` -> `for (var i = 0, maxI = splits.length; i < maxI; ++i)`

Comment: Do you have any problems with current performance?

Comment: @Virus721: No, that's irrelevant premature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestions?

Yes, a few.

First off, split your function into parts ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)), to separate the view (DOM elements and their values) from the logic (finding element names in strings).

> ```
> var splits = fname.split("");
> for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
>     var onevalue = fname.indexOf(splits[i]);
> ```

That doesn't make much sense to me. Don't you expect `onevalue == i`? If not, you might annotate this explicitly and/or make the comparison. Maybe it's inside the "some code"?

> ```
> var doublev = fname.substring(onevalue, onevalue + 2);
> var triplev = fname.substring(onevalue, onevalue + 3);
> ```

Notice that these will have the same value as `singlev` in the last [two] iterations of your loop, where the end is outside of the string.

> ```
> if (ellist[splits[i]] || ellist[doublev] || ellist[triplev]) {
>     value = splits[i];
>     if (ellist[doublev] || ellist[triplev]) {
>         value = ellist[doublev];
>         if (ellist[triplev]) {
>             value = ellist[triplev];
> ```

Ouch. Simplify this to

```
if (triplev in ellist) {
    value = ellist[triplev];
} else if (doublev in ellist) {
    value = ellist[doublev];
} else if (splits[i] in ellist) { // are you sure you don't want `singlev`?
    value = splits[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function should take `firstname` and `lastname` arguments as strings.  If you need to retrieve the strings from DOM elements, make a wrapper function.  (You actually screwed this up in the code, treating DOM elements as if they were strings.)

This code is unnecessarily verbose:

```
var singlev = fname.substring(onevalue, onevalue + 1);
var doublev = fname.substring(onevalue, onevalue + 2);
var triplev = fname.substring(onevalue, onevalue + 3);
if (ellist[splits[i]] || ellist[doublev] || ellist[triplev]) {
    value = splits[i];

    if (ellist[doublev] || ellist[triplev]) {
        value = ellist[doublev];

        if (ellist[triplev]) {
            value = ellist[triplev];
            // some code here
        }
        // some code here
    }
    // some code here
}
```

You could just say

```
var singlev = fname.charAt(i);
var doublev = fname.substring(onevalue, onevalue + 2);
var triplev = fname.substring(onevalue, onevalue + 3);
value = ellist[triplev] || ellist[doublev] || ellist[singlev];
```